# Mission Control key on a Mac keyboard

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, multitasking-view

I have a Mac keyboard and I would like to know if I could use the Mission Control key (f3) instead of Super+s (Multitasking view) on Loki.

I tried to set it up, but the closest I got is super+f3, but I'm not too happy about that.